# Matlab :how to get indices of the filtered output

Tags: matlab

I am designing a filter for a wavfile , actually what i want to do is to separate a band of certain frequencies , amplify them and then add them back to the wav file

```
[y Fs]=wavread('test_2.wav');
Wp = [1100 2200]/Fs; 
Ws = [1000 2500]/Fs;
Rp = 3; Rs = 40;
[n,Wn] = buttord(Wp,Ws,Rp,Rs)
[b,a] = butter(n,Wn);

z=filter(b,a,y);
gain = 20;
filtered = gain .* z;
```

what i have managed to do to separate the certain band through a band pass filter and amplify it with a scaler now i want to add it back to the wav file , is there any built-in command through which i can  get the exact indices of the filtered output (find() doesn't work )

Comment: I recommend using Fourier transform for that matter. In the frequency domain you can directly choose what you want to amplify. Look for (Fast Fourier Transform) fft in your matlab help. Cheers

Comment: actually I must apply different band pass filters for this task

Comment: In the frequency domain you can apply any filter you want. it is just a matter of choosing a function that varies between 0 and 1 and multiply by your spectra. Then you preserve the frequencies when multiplying them by 1 and suppress those when multiplying by 0. Obviously you can use values in between to attenuate different frequencies, instead of completely suppressing them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filtfilt`.

> y = filtfilt(b,a,x) performs zero-phase digital filtering by processing the input data, x, in both the forward and reverse directions.

So in your case,

```
z = filtfilt(b,a,y);
gain = 20;
filtered = gain .* z;
y = y + filtered;
```